# Parse Push Notification in Cordova App

Tags: android, ios, git, cordova, parse-platform

I have a cordova project in Android and iOS.

I've trying to connect Parse with my project, I've seen some tutorials but all of them couldn't help me.

iOS:
Initially in this tutorial  https://github.com/francimedia/PushPlugin/tree/feature/parse, When I add the plugin automatically (cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git) to my project and tried to build, it show me this error :
 "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      -[PFKeychainStore setObject:forKey:] in Parse(PFKeychainStore.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal i386
(1 failure)

Or when a tried to add it manually, when a I add Parse.framework to my project, show me the same error.

Android:
I use the following tutorial http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/10/10/PhoneGap-Parsecom-and-Push-Notifications, When a I edit the MainActivity.java file and build the project show me a error. Or when I try to used the https://github.com/francimedia/PushPlugin/tree/feature/parse for Android  and I add a the javascript code in my html, It doesnt work.

I hope some here can help, if I have to start again i'll do it, I just want it to work.

Comment: Are you able to solve this problem. I am facing the same and pulling my hair since few days!

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I have the same issue